# Android Studio Code Format adds empty Strings

Tags: java, android-studio, code-formatting

I have this line in a Java file in Android Studio:

```
MyClass.staticX(myMethod(), String.format("Hello I am a demo text. A: %s, Here comes AA: %s.", OtherCoolClass.longMethodNameWithVeryMuchMeaningYo(omg), andTheLastArgument));
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it gets to this:

```
MyClass.staticX(myMethod(), String.format("Hello I am a demo text. A: %s, Here comes AA: " +
        "%s.", OtherCoolClass.longMethodNameWithVeryMuchMeaningYo(omg), 
        andTheLastArgument));
```

So far so cool, but with every following code format, Android Studio adds another `"" +` to the second line, thus after a few formattings, this comes out:

```
MyClass.staticX(myMethod(), String.format("Hello I am a demo text. A: %s, Here comes AA: " +
        "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" +
        "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "" + "%s.",
        OtherCoolClass.longMethodNameWithVeryMuchMeaningYo(omg), andTheLastArgument));
```

I am not very happy about that. Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? Why *is* that even happening?

Comment: lol, this is hilarious! Are you on stable build? Or dev/canary?  xD

Comment: *Why?* I can only imagine that this is a bug. And a funny one ;-)

Comment: @varun: I am on stable 3.1.3...